# date.setHours() not working

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to subtract hours from a given date time string using javascript.
My code is like:

```
     var cbTime = new Date();    
     cbTime = selectedTime.setHours(-5.5);
```

Where `selectedTime` is the given time (time that i pass as parameter).

So suppose `selectedTime`  is `Tue Sep 16 19:15:16 UTC+0530 2014`
 Ans I get is : `1410875116995`

I want answer in datetime format.
Am I doing something wrong here? Or there is some other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `setHours()`, `setMinutes()`, etc, take an `Integer` as a parameter. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes):

> ...
>
> `The setMinutes()` method sets the minutes for a specified date
>   according to local time.
>
> ...
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> An integer between 0 and 59, representing the minutes.

So, you could do this:

```js
var selectedTime = new Date(),
    cbTime = new Date(); 
   
cbTime.setHours(selectedTime.getHours() - 5);
cbTime.setMinutes(selectedTime.getMinutes() - 30);

document.write('cbTime: ' + cbTime);
document.write('<br>');
document.write('selectedTime: ' + selectedTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well first off setting the hours to `-5.5` is nonsensical, the code will truncate to an integer (`-5`) and then take that as "five hours before midnight", which is 7PM yesterday.

Second, `setHours` (and other functions like it) *modify* the Date object (try `console.log(cbTime)`) and *return* the timestamp (number of milliseconds since the epoch).

You should not rely on the output format of the browser converting the Date object to a string for you, and should instead use `get*()` functions to format it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

According to this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp

You'll get "Milliseconds between the date object and midnight January 1 1970" as a return value of setHours.

Perhaps you're looking for this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_sethours3

**Edit:**
If you want to subtract 5.5 hours, first you have to subtract 5 hours, then 30 minutes. Optionally you can convert 5.5 hours to 330 minutes and subtract them like this:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - 330);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
  var cbTime = new Date();
        cbTime.setHours(cbTime.getHours() - 5.5)
        cbTime.toLocaleString();
```

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
 var cbTime = new Date();
    cbTime.setHours(cbTime.getHours() - 5.5)
    cbTime.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: That will not work. "5.5" will be converted to int "5". Did you try it before posting the answer?